# Python Xarray `Dataset.sel()` select multiple values along one dimension

Tags: python-xarray

Suppose I have a `dataset` of type `xarray.Dataset`. I have a dimension named `name`, (shared by all the `DataArray`s in the `Dataset` but I don't think that's important for this question,) and I want to select an entry with a specific name. I would do this as follows.

```
dataset.sel(name="lucifer")
```

But suppose I now want to select a sub-dataset containing the names "lucifer" *and* "judas". I would want to do something like:

```
dataset.sel(name=["lucifer", "judas"])
```

because this is the closest syntax to Pandas that I can imagine. But this gives me an error.

```
InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

(Incidentally, every single error I get from Xarray seems to be this exact error, and I would be really happy to see Xarray give more informative errors.) **So my question is, how do I select by multiple named values from a named dimension?** Assume that the named values have no particular ordering, so I can't use slices for example.

Comment: Do you really need a dimension that isn't unique? I've generally found it much easier to reason about datasets with unique dimensions. Where there is non-unique data for labelling, you can use coords.

Comment: @Maximilian I don't really understand what you mean by non-unique dimensions. All I'm asking is to select two (or more) unique values along a dimension. The dimension itself is unique too.

Comment: Are you sure the values on that dimension are unique? If they are, what you wrote should work. Could you post a fuller example?

Answer (score 1):

In xarray, you can use the `sel` method with the `isin` method to select multiple values along a dimension. Here's how you can select a sub-dataset containing the names "lucifer" and "judas":

```
Evil_dataset = dataset.sel(name=dataset.name.isin(["lucifer", "judas"]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a unique index for your dimensions, then you can use `where` over non-unique coords:

```
In [11]: ds=xr.Dataset({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': ('a', [4,5,5])})
In [14]: ds.where(ds.b==5, drop=True)
Out[14]: 
<xarray.Dataset>
Dimensions:  (a: 2)
Coordinates:
  * a        (a) int64 2 3
Data variables:
    b        (a) float64 5.0 5.0
```